# Accessing message menu with my ubuntu phone click apps / Apps in background

Tags: ubuntu-touch, indicator, indicator-message, background-process

in sdk's API documentation

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/qml/api/

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/api/

I cannot find examples how to send notifications to central message menu. Did I miss this doc? Are there some examples (qml and html5) or can anyone who knows about this system give any hints?

Anyway message indication implies that (or just makes sense when) apps are able to run in the background. Currently I just can see that near all apps are doomed to be in the foreground (Except phone, music, and system settings etc.).

Due I cannot imagine that self written apps won't have access to background-processing (e.g. like indicators in unity-desktop), I would also be interested to have some facts about how App-Programers should code their apps to run in the background.

Thanks